# iOS change cell color ( based on row)

Tags: ios, colors, cell

I want the background color of my cells to change depending on the row. I'm using this code. Why are all cells red?

```
CGFloat proportion = indexPath.row/(float)rows;
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(proportion*255) green:0.0f  blue:0.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEaed.png)

But if I use this code the color show normally

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:proportion alpha:1.0f];
```

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgJHq.png)

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: try to set `cell.contentView.backgroundColor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U count it wrong

U proportion * 255 is bigger than 1

use just proportion

Answer (score 1):

Don't multi with 255. The color value is in range [0,1.0]

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:proportion green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0f];
```

The `red`, `green`, `blue` and `alpha` parameter is between 0.0 ~ 1.0. If it exceeds 1.0, it will be treated as 1.0.